# Cross-Compiling a Kernel Object from MIPS Linux to ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mips, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I have driver .ko file that needs to be included in an Arm kernel using sabrelite board. However I don't and can't take hold of the source code for this driver. Is it possible to cross compile this module for ARM?

Comment: In which framework your are building your image as Linux contains contains architecture specific header files like string.h one of them

Comment: If you don't have the source, then it's not exactly possible to _compile_ it in any manner...

Comment: The .ko file I have is inside a MIPS32 machine and I want to build for ARMv7 with linux kernel 3.0.35

Comment: It's _already_ built; to "build for ARMv7" would first require **un**-building it, and that is going to be almost impossibly difficult (i.e. potentially also having to analyse/decompile large parts of the kernel it was built against).